# Characteristic curves of a partial differantial equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to find the general solution of the pde:

$ x(x+y)u_{x} - y(x+y)u_{y} = -(x-y)(2x+2y+u) $

My opinion:

The characteristic equation of the pde is $ {dx \over x(x+y)}={dy \over -y(x+y)} = {du \over  -(x-y)(2x+2y+u)} $

Then firstly, use $ {dx \over x(x+y)}={dy \over -y(x+y)} \implies $ $ {dx \over x}={dy \over -y} \implies lnx=-lny+lnc_{1} \implies lnc_{1}=lnx+lny \implies xy=c_{1}:= \phi(x,y,u) $ is the first characteristic curve.

But now, I wasn't able to find a way to find the second curve. Because it seems impossible to make a relation with the $du$ part..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x(x+y)u_x-y(x+y)u_y=-(x-y)(2x+2y+u)$

$xu_x-yu_y=-2(x-y)-\dfrac{(x-y)u}{x+y}$

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=x$ , letting $x(0)=1$ , we have $x=e^t$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=-y$ , letting $y(0)=y_0$ , we have $y=y_0e^{-t}=\dfrac{y_0}{x}$

$\dfrac{du}{dt}=-2(x-y)-\dfrac{(x-y)u}{x+y}=-2(e^t-y_0e^{-t})-\dfrac{(e^t-y_0e^{-t})u}{e^t+y_0e^{-t}}$

$\dfrac{du}{dt}+\dfrac{(e^t-y_0e^{-t})u}{e^t+y_0e^{-t}}=-2(e^t-y_0e^{-t})$

I.F. $=e^{\int\frac{e^t-y_0e^{-t}}{e^t+y_0e^{-t}}dt}=e^{\int\frac{d(e^t+y_0e^{-t})}{e^t+y_0e^{-t}}}=e^{\ln(e^t+y_0e^{-t})}=e^t+y_0e^{-t}$

$\therefore\dfrac{d((e^t+y_0e^{-t})u)}{dt}=-2(e^t-y_0e^{-t})(e^t+y_0e^{-t})$

$(e^t+y_0e^{-t})u=-2\int(e^{2t}-y_0^2e^{-2t})~dt$

$(e^t+y_0e^{-t})u=-e^{2t}-y_0^2e^{-2t}+f(y_0)$

$u=\dfrac{f(y_0)-e^{2t}-y_0^2e^{-2t}}{e^t+y_0e^{-t}}$

$u(x,y)=\dfrac{f(xy)-x^2-y^2}{x+y}$